# auctex and pdf-tools reverse search change keybinding

Tags: key-bindings, auctex, pdf-tools

Inverse search from pdf-tools to auctex uses Ctrl-click on the pdf file to go to the corresponding part of latex file. Is it possible to also assign Alt-click to do inverse search? I am using ubuntu 18.04 (in case the OS is relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to know the keymap used by `pdf-sync-minor-mode`. Normally this will be something like `pdf-sync-minor-mode-map`. You can find out by calling `C-h v`, then using tab completion to get the full name. In this case, it is indeed `pdf-sync-minor-mode-map`.

Now you can use the function `define-key` to bind your new key to the map. This function takes three arguments: the keymap, the key, and the function. The syntax for binding a mouse click is `[mouse-1]`, or `[M-mouse-1]` for clicking with the Alt key pressed. So:

```
(eval-after-load 'pdf-sync
  '(define-key pdf-sync-minor-mode-map 
    [M-mouse-1] 
    'pdf-sync-backward-search-mouse))
```

I used `eval-after-load` to make sure the code isn't run until *after* `pdf-sync` is loaded.

Comment: I followed the instructions and indeed pdf-sync-minor-mode-map  is correct. But when I put the suggested code in my .emacs file, I get the response  ``Symbol's function definition is void: pdf-sync-minor-mode-map''.  Maybe I need to specify in the .emacs file the specific minor mode for it to work? I dont know how to do this.

Comment: Did you copy that error message directly? It doesn't really make sense, unless it actually reads "Symbol's function definition is void: pdf-sync-backward-search-engine". In any case, it suggests the pdf-tools package isn't loaded before you run the code. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you sir! It now works perfectly!